# Android HttpUrlConnection Cannot Post - Error 403

Tags: android, spring, spring-security, csrf

I'm trying to issue a HttpPost against my webservice with spring security csrf.

first, I'm trying to recover the XSRF TOKEN through a GET request, like this

```
public static CookieManager xcsrfToken() throws IOException{
    String token;
    URL url = new URL(urlBase);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
    con.connect();

    List<String> cookieHeader = con.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");

    if (cookieHeader != null) {
        for (String cookie : cookieHeader) {
            cookieManager.getCookieStore().add(null, HttpCookie.parse(cookie).get(0));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(con.getHeaderFields());
    con.disconnect();

    return cookieManager;
}
```

This is what i get from the con.getHeaderFields()

```
{null=[HTTP/1.1 200 OK], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate], Content-Language=[pt-BR], Content-Length=[973], Content-Type=[text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1], Date=[Wed, 19 Aug 2015 10:40:18 GMT], Expires=[0], Pragma=[no-cache], Server=[Apache-Coyote/1.1], Set-Cookie=[JSESSIONID=6C9326FBEEA14752068720006F2B5EAA; Path=/webapi/; HttpOnly, XSRF-TOKEN=07cbed7f-834e-4146-8537-0a6b5669f223; Path=/], X-Android-Received-Millis=[1439980819720], X-Android-Response-Source=[NETWORK 200], X-Android-Sent-Millis=[1439980819693], X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], X-Frame-Options=[DENY], X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block]}
```

The XSRF-TOKEN is in my cookie, ok!
If I print then with
System.out.println(cookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies());
I got this

```
[JSESSIONID=5B1D3E2D3E7B3E1E6572A3839BFF3741, XSRF-TOKEN=4d4048bd-f21c-48c6-895e-5f67523ad963]
```

Now, I'm trying to issue a POST against the server, like this

```
public static HttpURLConnection makeRequest(String metodo, String uri, String requestBody) throws IOException{
    URL url = new URL(urlBase + uri);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");

    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setDoOutput(!metodo.equals("GET"));
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", TextUtils.join("," , xcsrfToken().getCookieStore().getCookies()));

    con.connect();

    InputStream is = con.getErrorStream();
    System.out.println(IOUtils.toString(is, "UTF-8"));

    System.out.println(con.getHeaderFields());

    return con;
}
```

But the header is comming back without the cookies

```
 {null=[HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate], Content-Language=[en], Content-Length=[1149], Content-Type=[text/html;charset=utf-8], Date=[Wed, 19 Aug 2015 10:42:18 GMT], Expires=[0], Pragma=[no-cache], Server=[Apache-Coyote/1.1], X-Android-Received-Millis=[1439980939827], X-Android-Response-Source=[NETWORK 403], X-Android-Sent-Millis=[1439980939811], X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], X-Frame-Options=[DENY], X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block]}
```

And it says that don't have a CSRF valid token

```
Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-XSRF-TOKEN'.
```

In my webservice, the tokens is configured to rename to XSRF-TOKEN because of angularJs.

**SOLUTION**

```
public static void getTokens() throws IOException{
    URL url = new URL(urlBase);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.connect();
    cookieManager = new CookieManager();

    List<String> cookieHeader = con.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");

    if (cookieHeader != null) {
        for (String cookie : cookieHeader) {
            String[] tokens = TextUtils.split(cookie, "=");
            if (tokens[0].equals("JSESSIONID"))
                cookieManager.getCookieStore().add(null, HttpCookie.parse(cookie).get(0));
            if (tokens[0].equals("XSRF-TOKEN")) {
                String[] tokenValue = TextUtils.split(tokens[1],";");
                xsrfTOKEN = tokenValue[0];
            }
        }
    }

    con.disconnect();
}
```

Then, attach it to HttpUrlConnection

```
con.setRequestProperty("X-XSRF-TOKEN", xsrfTOKEN);
```

Comment: What is printed when you send `xcsrfToken().getCookieStore().getCookies()` to logcat?

Comment: This, [JSESSIONID=5B1D3E2D3E7B3E1E6572A3839BFF3741, XSRF-TOKEN=4d4048bd-f21c-48c6-895e-5f67523ad963]

Comment: The cookies are supposed to be delimited by a `;` on the request. Perhaps that is where the error is? It'd also pay to debug your HTTP request using a reverse proxy like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) and modify it on the fly.

Comment: I tried with a semicolon, but keep getting the error.

I'll look for an example of the reverse proxy and make a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have experienced, we would need to submit the token as a request **header**. Spring expects its name to be `X-CSRF-TOKEN` by default. But people using AngularJS normally alter it to `X-XSRF-TOKEN` in Spring Security configuration.

But looking at your code, I couldn't figure out if you are sending that header.

If it would help, here is a snippet from my one project (using *RestAssured*):

```
if (xsrfToken != null && !ctx.getRequestMethod().equals(Method.GET))
    requestSpec.header("X-XSRF-TOKEN", xsrfToken);
```

Comment: This part of the code is setting the X-XSRF-TOKEN, ```con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", TextUtils.join("," , xcsrfToken().getCookieStore().getCookies()));```

I'm trying to send it like a Cookie, cuz I can't figure out how to split the cookieManager to send separated headers

Comment: That's what I doubt. I think that it must be sent as a separate header.

Comment: Or, I think as a request parameter, named `_crsf` by default.